# Avoid /run/user type of paths in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Not sure if this is a Ubuntu question or a Python question;

I have just cloned my repository on a new Ubuntu 20.04 PC.

My program opens a file with a pyqt file dialogue `getOpenFileName`.
The file I am opening is located in `/home/user/documents/myfolder/myfile.txt` however the path I get from the file dialogue is `'/run/user/1000/doc/97e866e2/myfile.txt'`.

The program expects that the folder where the file is would contain other files as well, and because the path is "magically" beign changed the program cannot find those.

- Is this a python thing or something of Ubuntu?
- How can I ensure the obtaining of the real path?

thanks

Comment: It would help to provide details about this "program". Maybe it has configurations or options for setting the working directory. Maybe it has a README to explain how to set the paths. Without details, people would just be guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be an issue with PyCharm. Just check to see if the code is running in PyCharm, and if it is, use the built-in QFileDialog. Otherwise, use the native dialog. You should get the correct path in both cases.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if "PYCHARM_HOSTED" in os.environ:
    ret, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Window Title',
            '/path/to/file/location',
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog,
        )
else:
    ret, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Window Title',
            '/path/to/file/location',
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the fact that PyCharm is running as a snap application that causes the problem. I check for the `SNAP` environment variable.

```
kwargs = {}
if 'SNAP' in os.environ:
    kwargs['options'] = QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                           'Open puzzle',
                                           dir=save_dir,
                                           filter='Text files (*.txt)',
                                           **kwargs)
```